# Можно ли сделать игру на Pygame, для того чтобы в нее могли играть в телеграме через бота по вебхуку?

Tags: html5, telegram-bot, разработка-игр, telegram, pygame

Можно ли сделать игру на Pygame, для того чтобы в нее могли играть в телеграме через бота по вебхуку? Или мне нужна другая библиотека и язык возможно, но хотелось бы на питоне!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pygame является оберткой над SDL, которая в свою очередь представляет удобный интерфейс для обработки событий окон, звуковой карты, гироскопа, вибро, сетевой карты и т.д. Это инструмент для игровых клиентов, но скорее для игровых движков.

Ваша задумка вполне реализуема, но нужно учесть, что грамотнее будет серверную часть c API для ботов отделить от монитора для игрового мира, который придется делать отдельным клиентом для другого сервера, который будет раздавать состояние игры.

Если в качестве монитора вы не хотите использовать окна и отдельный клиент, а хотите рисовать состояния в сообщениях мессенджера, то вам Pygame не нужен, и подойдет любое решение для написания ботов.

Если вы хотите встроить сам мессенджер в игровой клиент, то Pygame вам понадобится для не-текстового монитора игры.